# Search for related entries based on tags

Tags: tags, search

On an entry page I search for related entries based on the tags assigned to the respective entry. The following example works:

```
{% set tags = entry.q_tags.first %}

{% for tag in entry.q_tags.offset(1) %}
    {% set tags = tags ~ ' OR ' ~ tag  %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.search(tags).order('score') %}
```

I just wonder whether there is a smarter solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the accepted answer actually works, `order: 'score'` only works if you are doing a search.

I've made a plugin called [Similar](https://github.com/aelvan/Similar-Craft) that orders by the number of relations to other element types, like tags.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
{% set tags = entry.q_tags %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tags).order('score').find() %}
```

Comment: Do you not want to pass an array in this situation? I.e. omit the `.first` to make `{% set tags = entry.q_tags %}` and then just pass that to the relatedTo param.

Comment: Didn't notice the 'first' :)

Comment: How would you stop the current entry from displaying as a related entry?

Comment: Try adding .id('not ' ~ entry.id) to your criteria.

Comment: Ordering by `'score'` only works in the context of doing a `search: 'something'`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you would exclude the current entry from showing within that output if so desired

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  relatedTo:      tags,
  order:          'score',
  limit:           4,
  id:             'not ' ~ entry.id
}) %}
```

Comment: Ordering by `'score'` only works in the context of doing a `search: 'something'`.