# GraphQL - Get related entries based on tags field

Tags: craft3, relatedto, graphql

I'm trying to retrieve entries related to the current entry, based on a `tag` field called `topics`. Simple stuff.

Now, I use Craft's native GraphQL implementation so I'm bound to the possibilities this interface gives me. In twig, it would be quite easily solved as described in the following topic: [Search for related entries based on tags](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/search-for-related-entries-based-on-tags)

It seems like the `relatedTo` property of the `entries()` query only supports a single ID, without the ability to scope my results based on a certain field. I would expect to be able to do something like the following:

```
entries(
    section: "article",
    limit: 2,
    relatedTo: {
        sourceElement: 123, // ID of the current entry
        field: 'topics'
    }
) {
    id,
    title
}
```

This just gives me the following error: `Expected type [Int], found {sourceElement: 123, field: \"topics\"}.`

Now, if I resort to the documentation it indeed describes that only an entry's ID can be used as the value of `relatedTo`, like this:

```
query QueryName {
  entries(
      section: "article",
      limit: 2,
      relatedTo: 123 // Current article ID
  ) {
      id,
      title
  }
}
```

This does work (it doesn't error), but results in an empty `entries` array. Even though there's entries that have the same `topics` (tags) assigned to them.

I'm kinda lost on how to actually retrieve related entries. Should I just revert to using the `search` param and feed it a concatenated list of the current post's tags?

Any elegant solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here but wouldn't passing the current entry's tag IDs rather than the entry ID work for you?

```
query QueryName {
  entries(
      section: "article",
      limit: 2,
      relatedTo: [123,456] // Current article's tag IDs?
  ) {
      id,
      title
  }
}
```